# An inconstructible quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

A student tried to draw a quadrilateral $STOP$ with $ST=5cm$, $TO=4cm$, $\angle S = 20^{\circ}, \angle T = 30^{\circ}, \angle O = 40^{\circ}$. But he found out that it was impossible to construct one.We have to show why he failed without using trigonometry.

At first,we calculate the remaining angle P, $\angle P = 270^{\circ}$.But after that,I am stuck.Obviously either of the side lengths is messing things up.But I cannot seem to find any way to show that.A small hint at this point will be appreciated.

Comment: How many angles does your triangle have?

Comment: Why does this triangle have four vertices?

Comment: @hardmath@Hagen,I am sorry for my mistake.It was supposed to be a quadrilateral.

Answer (score 3):

The non-convex quadrilateral $STOP$ below satisfies the hypotheses of the question.

[image]

The question is, can we *construct* it, using only the Euclidean straightedge and collapsible compass tools? I had to resort to using a protractor to measure out the $20^{\circ}$ and $40^{\circ}$ angles in order to draw the diagram above, which doesn't count.

So it all boils down to whether or not $20^{\circ}$ angles are constructable, or rather, whether or not there is a general way to trisect an angle. [It can't be done.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection) The student referred to in your question was naively attempting to accomplish exactly that, and so doomed.

Comment: Ah, that makes some sense of the problem.  Obviously most high school math classes would not have this level of sophistication, but it really isn't stated what the problem's context is.

Comment: Hmm,the question does not mention the student using only a compass and a straightedge.When I first tried to draw the non-convex quadrilateral,and I somehow managed to,I thought I had drawn something inaccurate by a small scale.But I think the question tries to exclude possibilities of a non convex quadrilateral.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that it is possible to construct such a quadrilateral.  Perhaps some problem has crept into giving the data?

Given that the angle at $T$ is supposed to be 30 degrees, we can reconstruct triangle $STO$ using only the side lengths $ST$ and $TO$ according to the familiar Pythagorean relationship and facts about the "special triangle" having 30-60-90 degree angles.  [If those facts are not allowed as "using trigonometry", it seems doubtful that any approach using the available angle information would be allowed.]

That is, if we drop a perpendicular from shorter side's vertex $O$ onto $ST$ (the longer side) at point $Q$, then $TQO$ will be a right triangle with hypotenuse $TO$ of length 4cm.  It follows from facts about this "special triangle" with angle at $T$ being 30 degrees that $QO$ has half the length of the hypotenuse (2cm) and that $TQ$ has length $2\sqrt{3}$ cm.

Accordingly $SQO$ is also a right triangle, sharing the side $QO$ and having side $SQ$ of length $5 - 2\sqrt{3}$ cm.  The hypotenuse $SO$ of this second right triangle is therefore of length $\sqrt{4 + (5-2\sqrt{3})}$ cm.

As pointed out in the Question, the internal angle at $P$ must be 270 degrees, so the external angle at $P$ is 90 degrees.  Therefore $P$ lies on the semi-circle with diameter $SO$.  Drawing the sides $OP$ and $SP$ at angles 40 and 20 degrees respectively to sides $TO$ and $ST$ will therefore produce a quadrilateral with all the required data.

Comment: I think the textbook tries to exclude non convex quadrilaterals,but there is no indication to support my belief.

Comment: Btw,figuring out the  relevant properties of the "special triangle" does not require trigonometry.You can use an equilateral triangle and fold it in half to figure out the ratios.

Comment: @DavidH: I'm sure the above is about the 30-60-90 right triangle being "half" of an equilateral triangle.  If the impossibility of this problem hinges on not being able to measure off a 20 degree angle, it seems a little more elaborate than necessary for the purpose.

Comment: @David H,I was talking about the 30-60-90 triangle,not all triangles.And I don't think the impossibility of this problem hinges on not being able to trisect an angle.I am pretty  sure the student was allowed a protractor.